Different SPI Responses (0x4F on Arduino, 0x7F on Raspberry Pi) from the Same SPI Slave
I’m having an issue with SPI communication where the same SPI slave (a sensor) is returning different data on the MISO pin. When I use an Arduino, I get the expected response of 0x4F from the SPI slave. However, when using a Raspberry Pi, I receive 0x7F instead.
Here are the details:
SPI Mode: CPOL = 0, CPHA = 0 (Mode 0) on both devices.
Clock frequency: I’ve tried adjusting the SPI clock frequency on the Raspberry Pi, but it didn’t resolve the issue.
Here are two screenshots showing the SPI waveforms for both cases:
Raspberry Pi (0x7F):

Arduino (0x4F):

Additional details:
The wiring for MOSI, MISO, SCK, and CS is identical in both cases.
Does anyone have an idea why the SPI communication on the Raspberry Pi is not returning the expected response?
Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!

What logic level voltages are used by the Arduino and pi respectively? I mean doesn't the pi run at a rail voltage of 3.3 volts whereas the Arduino is 5 volts? What voltage supply is on the slave?

The values of CPOL and CPHA are not universal, they can mean different modes on different MCUs. And the transmissions are not identical, the one that works has a huge delay between bytes, the one that does not sends bytes back to back. Are they using the same clock frequency and is it within limits?

Yes, the Arduino is at 5Volts and the RPi at 3.3V. This is why i use a level shifter. For the use of the RPi i have modified the level shifter. Maybe i take a close look at the circuit again.
For the SPI Mode (CPOL/CPHA) i use the standard Libs for Arduino and RPi both on Mode 0. I do not expect them to differ in the interpretation of the modes but i wiill check that as well.

Level shifters can induce delays which can cause issues, especially if they are different for different lines. It can help to measure at various points in the circuit to see if there is a difference (for example CLK and MISO at the RPi / Arduino and CLK and MISO at the slave).

@thomas0721 You forgot to say what the sensor is and completely omitted an impotant fact about level shifter being used, and completely left the level shiter type as a secret, also the connections between devices and the shifter. We can't possibly know what's wrong without these important details.
